# Repeated lines in PdfPTable at the end of the page?

Tags: itext, pdfptable

I'm using a PdfPTable (iText) to print a table that is populated with some list of values.

The problem is that, in the case where the PdfPTable takes more than one page to be displayed, its last line is printed at the end of the first page and **ALSO** at the beginning of the second one.

Please find an example below :

[image]

---

**EDIT :**

Please find the code below :

```
protected static PdfPTable addUserList(PdfWriter writer, Document document, List<MyObject> objects) throws Exception {

    PdfPTable headerTable = new PdfPTable(4);
    headerTable.setWidthPercentage(100);
    headerTable.setWidths(new int[] { 4, 7, 5, 3 });
    PdfPCell headerCell = PDFUtils.makeDefaultCell(1);
    headerCell.setBorderColor(Color.WHITE);
    headerCell.setBorder(PdfPCell.RIGHT);
    headerCell.setBorderWidth(1f);

    Phrase phrase = new Phrase("Column1", Style.OPIFICIO_12_BOLD_WHITE);
    headerCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    headerCell.setPhrase(phrase);
    headerTable.addCell(headerCell);

    phrase = new Phrase("Column2", Style.OPIFICIO_12_BOLD_WHITE);
    headerCell.setPhrase(phrase);
    headerCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    headerTable.addCell(headerCell);

    phrase = new Phrase("Column3", Style.OPIFICIO_12_BOLD_WHITE);
    headerCell.setPhrase(phrase);
    headerCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    headerTable.addCell(headerCell);

    phrase = new Phrase("Column4", Style.OPIFICIO_12_BOLD_WHITE);
    Chunk chunk = new Chunk("(1)", Style.OPIFICIO_6_BOLD_WHITE);
    chunk.setTextRise(7f);
    phrase.add(chunk);
    chunk = new Chunk("(XX)", Style.OPIFICIO_8_BOLD_WHITE);
    chunk.setTextRise(1f);
    phrase.add(chunk);
    headerCell.setPhrase(phrase);
    headerCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    headerCell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    headerTable.addCell(headerCell);

    PdfPTable userTable = new PdfPTable(4);
    userTable.setWidthPercentage(100);
    userTable.setWidths(new int[] { 4, 7, 5, 3 });
    PdfPCell cell = PDFUtils.makeDefaultCell(1);
    cell.setBackgroundColor(null);
    cell.setPaddingTop(2f);
    cell.setPaddingLeft(6f);
    cell.setPaddingRight(6f);

    for (MyObject object : objects) {

        if (object != null) {

            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);

            if (object.getAttribute1() != null) {
                phrase = new Phrase(object.getAttribute1(), Style.FUTURASTD_10_NORMAL_BLACK);
            } else {
                phrase = new Phrase("", Style.FUTURASTD_10_NORMAL_BLACK);
            }
            cell.setBorderWidth(1f);
            cell.setBorderColor(Color.WHITE);
            cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.RIGHT);
            cell.setPhrase(phrase);
            userTable.addCell(cell);

            phrase = new Phrase(object.getAttribute2(), Style.FUTURASTD_10_NORMAL_BLACK);
            cell.setBorderWidth(1f);
            cell.setBorderColor(Color.WHITE);
            cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.RIGHT);
            cell.setPhrase(phrase);
            userTable.addCell(cell);

            phrase = new Phrase(object.getAttribute3(), Style.FUTURASTD_10_NORMAL_BLACK);
            cell.setBorderWidth(1f);
            cell.setBorderColor(Color.WHITE);
            cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.RIGHT);
            cell.setPhrase(phrase);
            userTable.addCell(cell);

            phrase = new Phrase(object.getAttribute4(), Style.FUTURASTD_10_NORMAL_BLACK);
            cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            cell.setPhrase(phrase);
            userTable.addCell(cell);

        }
    }

    PdfPTable mainTable = new PdfPTable(1);
    mainTable.setWidthPercentage(100);
    mainTable.setSplitLate(false);
    mainTable.setHeaderRows(1);
    PdfPCell cellH = new PdfPCell();
    cellH.addElement(headerTable);
    cellH.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    cellH.setCellEvent(new PDFUtils.CellBackgroundRedRecap());
    mainTable.addCell(cellH);

    if (userTable.getRows().size() > 0) {
        PdfPCell cellUser = PDFUtils.makeDefaultCell(1);
        cellUser.setPaddingTop(7f);
        cellUser.setCellEvent(new PDFUtils.CellBackgroundRecap());
        cellUser.setBorder(PdfCell.NO_BORDER);
        cellUser.addElement(userTable);
        mainTable.addCell(cellUser);
    }

    return mainTable;
}
```

Comment: you should show relevant code.

Comment: That's probably a very old iText version. This sounds like a problem that was solved years ago. Which version are you using?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I'm using iText *2.1.7*. Please note that this feature is developed in our client site with the version *1.3.1* and in that solution this problem doesn't occur.

Comment: @GeomanYabes I've edited the question to include the code

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Also, we are using this dependancy `<dependency>
   <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
   <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.7</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: 2.1.7 ***is** a very old iText version*. As Bruno recognized this as *a problem that was solved years ago,* the obvious thing to do is update to the current 5.5.x version (or 7.0.x if you are up to a major re-write).

Comment: @mkl I've tried with the version 5.0.6 and the problem persists

Comment: @siho In which year do you live? If you live in **2017**, then why are you using version 5.0.6 which is a version that dates from February 4, **2011**. That version is *more than 6 years old!!!* Why are you making fun of us?

Comment: @Siho I proposed using 5.5.x, not 5.0.x...

Comment: @mkl Thank you for you valuable help. Actually, I was having an old version in the pom.xml of another module of my project that was conflicting with the one I was modifying. I've deleted it and now it works. Thank you again. If you could write an answer so that I can choose it as the right one.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thank you for your rude answer, it helps a lot !

Comment: @Siho "Spare the rod and spoil the child." I forgot all the teachers who were soft on me, but I am very grateful towards those teachers who kicked me in the behind.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thank you OHHH GREAT TEACHER Bruno. Glory to you ! GLORYYY  ! :D :D

Comment: @Siho Some people love me. Some people hate me. But regardless of whether they love or hate me, most people have one thing in common: they all want to be me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually was solved years ago (as @Bruno pointed out in a comment).

The solution, therefore, is to replace the older iText version used by a more current one in which the problem is fixed.

Indeed, the OP was having an old version in the pom.xml of another module of his project that was conflicting with the one he was modifying. He has deleted it and now it works.

---

Updating from versions 2.x (including the unofficial 4.2.0) to 5.x requires at least updating `import` statements as itext was moved from `com.lowagie` to `com.itextpdf`. Further changes might be necessary to adapt to actual API changes, e.g. the signing API was overhauled during the 5.3.x versions; the basic API structure, though, remained fairly stable during the 5.x versions.

Furthermore, updating from anything below 7 to 7.x requires greater changes as the whole iText API has been re-designed to get rid of sub-optimal aspects of the earlier API design.

Comment: I have to signal that the version 5.5.11 reduces the performance of the solution. In fact, with the version 2.1.7 we had the bug (for sure) but the execution time was 4 hours to generate about 100 000 PDF files, on the other hand, with the version 5.5.11, the bug is solved but the execution time is now 5 hours and half for the same 100 000 PDF files and with the same parameters.